# jQuery hover with fade timing problem w/ screenshot

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, jquery-hover

When hovering over a map bullet I'm fading out, changing the background position of the sprite, then fading back in. But I'm having a problem with consistency when this action is done quickly across several bullets.

Ideas how I can tweak this without having to make an specific event for each bullet?

[image]

```
$("#map a").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(200, function () {
      $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0 0');
      $(this).fadeIn(200);
    });
  },
  function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(200, function () {
      $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '');
      $(this).fadeIn(200);
    });
  }
);
```

### Thanks for the brain power!

...But I think I'm just going to remove this functionality in lieu of some fancy tooltips that don't mesh so well with the fading.  Thanks for stopping by!

Comment: please post a link to your website or put your code into js fiddle to demonstrate your issue

Comment: Going to move in a different direction -- see appended note above. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a demonstration, Im taking a guess that you need to stop your other bullets to achieve your desired effect using .stop()

```
$(this).stop(true, true).fadeOut(200, function () {
  $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0 0');
  $(this).stop(true, true).fadeIn(200);
});
```

Comment: I'll try and get a demo up. I've tried using the stop() in searching for a solution, but it seemed to stop the animation mid-fade, leaving it semi-opaque. In this snippet above, the bullet fades out but never returns & stops others from triggering. :\

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean value to check if you're currently animating something.

```
animating = false;

$('.something').hover(function() {
    if(animating) {
        return;
    }
    animating = true;
    $('.other').fadeOut(200, function() {
        animating = false;
    });
});
```